# Using Vue 3 for email rendering on express server

Tags: node.js, vue.js, express, webpack, server-side-rendering

As we use Vue for our frontend, I'm trying to introduce Vue also for our email templates on our node (express.js) server. Using `@vue/server-renderer` this works pretty well in general. So right now the process of sending an email on our express.js server looks like this:

1. Get all the data, which is necessary to render the email
2. Generate the content of the (html) email by using a Vue template, which looks similar to this:

```js
const { createSSRApp } = require('vue')
const { renderToString } = require('@vue/server-renderer')

module.exports = async (req, res, next) => {
  const app = createSSRApp({
    template: `
      <div>
        My email template
        {{ someDataVariable }}
      </div>
    `,
    computed: {
      someDataVariable () {
        return []
      }
    }
  })
 
  const htmlAsString = await renderToString(app)

  // ... send email with htmlAsString as content
}
```

For a better developer experience, we want to use single file components. Also we need to be able to make use of sub-components. So imports of other components should still work.
As the node server has no webpack set up, importing Vue files does not work.
Did anybody set this already up in a similar way? Is there a way to achieve this without webpack (maybe with vite)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [@vue/compiler-sfc](https://github.com/vuejs/core/tree/master/packages/compiler-sfc) which seems to be compatible with Vite.

[Vue 3 - SFC: How it works](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/single-file-component.html#how-it-works)